# Ack: permission denied outputs along with results

Tags: grep, macvim, ack

when I ack something I often get output like this:

```
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8c9698-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-mRPtTixYnWzzGcPpbIwx9scpDnE: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8cbba9-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-oARiyZ2BwCEskqiPzrfQd1FI_fI: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8d0b16-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-M8ARATBrrCt8Dzx_AUVyqQPlesE: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8df921-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-qOogYRrIy2P4eFSD0dps0axw41k: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8f25a5-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-.gfEmcarFxfuir1JeQeKjevK4Js: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8f66ac-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-A_iNHhXoUELEWtENxyYp8H_HsJA: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8f6ad6-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-xISGU82nDE6h.hGAKD7t8kfP3f0: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e8f6c43-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-8_4stPggeXhICZbspC7n3JPbbwU: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e9021f8-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-4LlZ.TfExXsf3L2woyFw9.LJF1U: Permission denied
Ack: tmp/nonces/4e90964d-https-www.google.com-kkEIoIiSEjUBRD.lRR_tT9V6ccE-MQcsEojzduPoDsosj.gnN5jPrmQ: Permission denied
```

What is this and how can I fix it/make it go away?

EDIT: this only happens in the MacVim output when I use the Ack plugin.  Normal Ack does not do this.

Comment: This is not an ack problem. It is a file permissions problem that you will have with any tool, not just ack.

Answer (score 3):

The `/tmp` directory is going to be used by users other than you , and you won't have permission to read those files or directories (even if you're the only one using the machine, various `root` processes will still use the `/tmp` dir).  There doesn't seem to be an `ack` option to not complain about permission problems, so you just have to discard those lines.  An easy way is to just throw out everything `ack` prints to `stderr`, like so:

```
alias ack='ack $* 2> /dev/null'
```

However, that will discard **all** `ack` errors.  To just discard the "Permission denied" errors requires a bit more work.  Assuming you're using `bash` as your shell, put this into your `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
function ack_discard_perm_errs()
{
    \ack --color $* 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
}

alias ack='ack_discard_perm_errs $*'
```

Comment: hmm..I added this to my bash profile (is that the same thing? I don't know much about bash) and it didn't do anything.  I should have clarified that I don't get any errors if I do it from command line, only when I use the Ack plugin for macvim.